# Can you have a list of lists in a properties/yml file?

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array, properties, yaml

I want a list of departments and within each department it will have  a list of emails.

Is this possible in properties/yml file?

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: It's also not clear what kind of properties file you're talking about. Spring, presumably? Java does not support YAML properties out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 4):

Java properties are a set of key-value pairs. They do not support lists at all. There are several workarounds, for example

```
a=lorem,ipsum,dolor # comma-separated; must be parsed manually after loading

# index in property name; must also be processed manually
b.1=lorem
b.2=ipsum
b.3=dolor
```

YAML does support lists and also nested lists, so you can do

```
- - lorem
  - ipsum
- - dolor
  - sit
  - amet
```

which loads as a list of two nested lists, one containing `lorem` and `ipsum`, the other containing `dolor`, `sit` and `amet`.